# how to minus negative values in sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using `SUM()` function. But `SUM()` sums the negative value in the column. In a column if the value is positive then it should be added and for negative values should be substracted and not added as the `SUM()`

```
20.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
-20.00
20.00
20.00
40.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
20.00
-20.00
-20.00
20.00
```

sum() should return 220 and not 440.
Is returning 440.

Comment: if you have 1,2,-2 as the rows in a column and you called sum on that the result would be 1. Is this not the behaviour you are getting?

Comment: if you add negative value to positive value - actually this is substraction 3 + (-5) = 3 -5 = -2

Comment: Please add some examples (edit your question): what data do you have, what does SUM() make of it, what do you want to get?

Comment: hmm, what is the data type of the column?

Comment: @hrishi In my example you are gettings 8 then? If so, can you show yor query and data what goes into query.

Comment: @hrishi - That **does** return 220 [Online Demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/115721/) Are you using it in a join that is doubling the number of rows being summed? It would be 340 if -ve numbers were being summed as positive.

Comment: @hrishi - Can you post your actual query so we can tell you how to fix it?

Comment: Martin thanks...the issue is fixed...it was returning double value...sorry for the pain guys

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To subtract negative numbers rather than add them you would use `SUM(ABS(col))` but just to check this is what you actually need example results below.

```
WITH YourTable(col) AS
(
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT -5 
)
SELECT 
       SUM(ABS(col)) AS [SUM(ABS(col))],
       SUM(col) AS [SUM(col)]
FROM YourTable
```

Returns

```
SUM(ABS(col)) SUM(col)
------------- -----------
7             -3
```

Answer (score 7):

`SELECT SUM(ABS(Column_Name)) FROM Table_Name;`